# How to specify relative file path in Java file so that it can still work after the file is put in jar file?

Tags: java, jar

Suppose I have a Java class that needs to access a file with absolute path
/home/gem/projects/bar/resources/test.csv:

```
package com.example
class Foo {
String filePath = ????? // path to test.csv
String lines = FileInputStream(new File(filePath).readAllLines();

}
```

Where the path to Foo.java is /home/gem/projects/bar/src/com/example.

Of course I cannot specify absolute path to the resource file. This is because jar file will be distributed as library for any clients to use in their own environments.

Assume the resource file like test.csv is always in the same path relative to project root. When a jar is created containing Foo.class, this jar also contains test.csv in the same relative path ( relative to project root).

What is the way to specify relative path that would work no matter where the project bar is moved to? Also how can I create a jar file (which can be in any location) so that the path to the resource file test.csv would still be correct.

To keep things simple, I have used invalid Java API ( readAllLines() which reads all the lines and return a string containing entire file content. Also not using try/catch).

Assume csv file can be read as well as written to.

I hope this makes it clear now.

Comment: "a relative path that would work no matter where the project is moved to" is a contradiction in terms - unless you move the resource file in the same way (i.e. the resource is part of the project). I guess that's the case for you, though. Why can't you "of course" specify an absolute path? Are you making a JAR or just running class files? What command are you using to run the program (including classpath), and from what starting directory?

Comment: As the CSV for read only, or is it necessary to write to it as well?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Must the csv be inside the jar, in the same directory where the jar is or any of them?

Answer (score 4):

Put the `test.csv` file into the `src` folder and use this:

```
Foo.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.csv")
```

To get an `InputStream` for the file. This will work wherever the project is moved, including packaged as a JAR file.

Comment: I want to keep resource files in its own directory. I cannot place them in the directory which is meant for Java source files.

Comment: @amc - you can make a resource directory which is also a source directory, it doesn't have to be just java code.  The point is that the file will be included in the jar and can be looked up from the classpath at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

ProjectX\src\Test.java

ProjectX\resources\config.properties

If you have the above structure and you want to use your config.properties file, this is how you do it:

InputStream input = new FileInputStream("./resources/config.projects");

In this example you don't have to worry about packaging your source into jar file. You can still modify your resources folder anytime.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`getResource()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29), as shown [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/googleolympiad).

Comment: As @Michael Borgwardt notes, you'll want `getResourceAsStream()`. Sorry about the bad link.