# How to write the path to include photos in my project

Tags: java, file, path

I want to add pictures my java project, but the bath i writes according to the location of the file in my device only, meaning that if I move the program to another device it will not work because the path is different

In other words, for example, If i write this path

> C:\Users\username\Documents\NetBeansProjects\src\img\photo.jpg

This path is not the same on all devices. I have to put the image with the program files in order for it to work on any device

**The question is**

**How do I write the path to work on any device and to be with the program files?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify relative file path in Java file so that it can still work after the file is put in jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447162/how-to-specify-relative-file-path-in-java-file-so-that-it-can-still-work-after-t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use relative paths.
If you put your image in a folder say, `resource` in your directory,
the path should be
`./resource/image.png`.
For moving upwards this directory, use `../` as in
`../resource/image.png`

Comment: Ok dude as i tried the run starts in the hole application folder then dist like this `applicationFolder\dist\application.jar`

but i want to put the images beside the`.jar` file to put the path of the image like this `\images\image.png`

to make the application works in any device

the question 
is how to make the application starts run from  the `.jar` file to put the images folder beside it directly?